# Why can't I compare result of lookup to Nothing in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
import System.Environment
import System.Directory
import System.IO
import Data.List

dispatch :: [(String, [String] -> IO ())]
dispatch =  [ ("add", add)
            , ("view", view)
            , ("remove", remove)
            , ("bump", bump)
            ]

main = do
    (command:args) <- getArgs
    let result = lookup command dispatch
    if result == Nothing then
        errorExit
    else do
        let (Just action) = result
        action args

errorExit :: IO ()
errorExit = do
    putStrLn "Incorrect command"

add :: [String] -> IO ()
add [fileName, todoItem] = appendFile fileName (todoItem ++ "\n")

view :: [String] -> IO ()
view [fileName] = do
    contents <- readFile fileName
    let todoTasks = lines contents
        numberedTasks = zipWith (\n line -> show n ++ " - " ++ line) [0..] todoTasks
    putStr $ unlines numberedTasks

remove :: [String] -> IO ()
remove [fileName, numberString] = do
    handle <- openFile fileName ReadMode
    (tempName, tempHandle) <- openTempFile "." "temp"
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    let number = read numberString
        todoTasks = lines contents
        newTodoItems = delete (todoTasks !! number) todoTasks
    hPutStr tempHandle $ unlines newTodoItems
    hClose handle
    hClose tempHandle
    removeFile fileName
    renameFile tempName fileName

bump :: [String] -> IO ()
bump [fileName, numberString] = do
    handle <- openFile fileName ReadMode
    (tempName, tempHandle) <- openTempFile "." "temp"
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    let number = read numberString
        todoTasks = lines contents
        bumpedItem = todoTasks !! number
        newTodoItems = [bumpedItem] ++ delete bumpedItem todoTasks
    hPutStr tempHandle $ unlines newTodoItems
    hClose handle
    hClose tempHandle
    removeFile fileName
    renameFile tempName fileName
```

Trying to compile it gives me the following error:

```
$ ghc --make todo
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( todo.hs, todo.o )

todo.hs:16:15:
    No instance for (Eq ([[Char]] -> IO ()))
      arising from a use of `=='
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Eq ([[Char]] -> IO ()))
    In the expression: result == Nothing
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      if result == Nothing then
          errorExit
      else
          do { let (Just action) = ...;
               action args }
    In the expression:
      do { (command : args) <- getArgs;
           let result = lookup command dispatch;
           if result == Nothing then
               errorExit
           else
               do { let ...;
                    .... } }
```

I don't get why is that since `lookup` returns `Maybe a`, which I'm surely can compare to `Nothing`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of the [`(==)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3a-61--61-) operator is `Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`.  What this means is that you can only compare objects for equality if they're of a type which is an instance of `Eq`.  And functions aren't comparable for equality: how would you write `(==) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Bool`?  There's no way to do it.<sup>1</sup>  And while clearly `Nothing == Nothing` and `Just x /= Nothing`, it's the case that `Just x == Just y` if and only if `x == y`; thus, there's no way to write `(==)` for `Maybe a` unless you can write `(==)` for `a`.

There best solution here is to use pattern matching.  In general, I don't find myself using that many `if` statements in my Haskell code.  You can instead write:

```
main = do (command:args) <- getArgs
          case lookup command dispatch of
            Just action -> action args
            Nothing     -> errorExit
```

This is better code for a couple of reasons.  First, it's shorter, which is always nice.  Second, while you simply *can't* use `(==)` here, suppose that `dispatch` instead held lists.  The `case` statement remains just as efficient (constant time), but comparing `Just x` and `Just y` becomes very expensive.  Second, you don't have to rebind `result` with `let (Just action) = result`; this makes the code shorter and doesn't introduce a potential pattern-match failure (which is bad, although you do know it can't fail here).

---

**1:**: In fact, it's impossible to write `(==)` while preserving referential transparency.  In Haskell, `f = (\x -> x + x) :: Integer -> Integer` and `g = (* 2) :: Integer -> Integer` ought to be considered equal because `f x = g x` for all `x :: Integer`; however, proving that two functions are equal in this way is in general undecidable (since it requires enumerating an infinite number of inputs).  And you can't just say that `\x -> x + x` only equals syntactically identical functions, because then you could distinguish `f` and `g` even though they do the same thing.

Comment: It might be worth adding that, although you can't implement `(==) :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Bool`, you _can_ implement `(== Nothing) :: Maybe a -> Bool`; the name of this function is [isNothing](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe+a+-%3E+Bool).

Answer (score 8):

The `Maybe a` type has an `Eq` instance only if `a` has one - that's why you get `No instance for (Eq ([[Char]] -> IO ()))` (a function can't be compared to another function).

Maybe the [maybe function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:maybe) is what you're looking for.  I can't test this at the moment, but it should be something like this:

```
maybe errorExit (\action -> action args) result
```

That is, if `result` is `Nothing`, return `errorExit`, but if `result` is `Just action`, apply the lambda function on `action`.

Comment: If you don't want to restructure your code, you should also be able to just replace `result == Nothing` with `isNothing result`

Comment: @JeffreyBurka, that qualifies as a separate answer in my mind.  Get your rightfully deserved reputation :)

Comment: Haha I'm going to leave it as a comment because technically the question was "why doesn't `==` work", not "how can I make it work". `maybe` is a cooler way of doing it anyway.

Comment: Note that `(\action -> action args)` can also be written as `($ args)`.